# LINQ Replace DBNull with Blank String

Tags: vb.net, linq, null, dbnull

In this example, an error is raised if either `row.FirstName` or `row.LastName` are `NULL`.

How do I rewrite the `Select` clause, to convert a DBNull value to a blank string `""`?

```
Dim query = From row As myDataSet.myDataRow in myDataSet.Tables("MyData") _
            Select row.FirstName, row.LastName
```

NOTE: Since the DataSet is strongly-typed.  I can use `row.isFirstNameNull()`, but `IIF(row.isFirstNameNull(), "", row.FirstName)` will not work since all parameters are referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your note you have mentioned `IIf(row.isFirstNameNull(), "", row.FirstName)` replace that with `If(row.isFirstNameNull(), "", row.FirstName)` which will not evaluate the false part if the condition is true

Answer (score 1):

Use [VB's ternary operator](http://www.rocksthoughts.com/blog/archive/2008/03/26/vb.net-true-ternary-operator-if.aspx) "if" :

```
Dim query = From row As myDataSet.myDataRow in myDataSet.Tables("MyData") _
    Select if(row.isFirstNameNull(), "", _
        row.FirstName), if(row.isLastNameNull(), "", row.LastName)
```

Answer (score -1):

what about `row.FirstName ?? string.Empty`

Comment: Works great for C# - not so much for VB.NET. VB.NET folks should use the If operator's coalesce form[1]: If(row.FirstName, string.Empty). Of course, that doesn't work for this example either - since DbNull.Value IsNot Nothing[2].

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx
[2] http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2004/04/12/11210.aspx